# Query from multiple MySQL tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following function which pulls in invoice data from tables invoices, however how can I get data from the customers table matching up invoice number:

So I guess need to get `* from customers tables where invoice = invoice`?

PHP

```
// the query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM invoices ORDER BY invoice ASC";

    // mysqli select query
    $results = $mysqli->query($query);

    // mysqli select query
    if($results) {

        print '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="data-table" cellspacing="0"><thead><tr>

                <th><h4>Invoice</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Customer</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Issue Date</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Due Date</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Status</h4></th>
                <th><h4>Action</h4></th>

              </tr></thead><tbody>';

        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

            print '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["invoice"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["customer_name"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["invoice_date"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["invoice_due_date"].'</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td><a href="invoice-edit.php?id='.$row["invoice"].'" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a> <a data-invoice-id="'.$row['invoice_id'].'" class="btn btn-danger delete-product">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            ';

        }

        print '</tr></tbody></table>';

    } else {

        echo "<p>There are no invoices to display.</p>";

    }
```

Comment: please mind considering this?
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I have been looking at that but really dont get how to do it, confusing... im new to PHP / MySQL you see.

Comment: @James You really need to just get your hands dirty. I normally don't jump to recommend w3schools, but a simple search for "learn mysql joins" should provide a wealth of information. There are really no shortcuts here. You have to learn how to do basic joins. They're not that hard.

Comment: I tried the following but does not seem to work, right direction? $query = "SELECT invoices.invoice, customers.customer_name, invoices.invoice_date, invoices.invoice_due_date
    FROM invoices
    INNER JOIN customers
    ON invoices.invoice=customers.invoice;"

Comment: even though i have answered your question, but you have to learn these basics, else you won't be able to work around in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's generally a better idea to include your keys in your `select` (and it's also easier to troubleshoot) instead of `*`.   However, assuming that these are your fields, you can connect these using a `JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoices i
JOIN customer c
ON c.invoice = i.invoice
ORDER BY i.invoice
```

Assuming you have a common key on each table, which as you suggest, is invoice (this is the huge advantage of using a database as opposed to a flat file), you can just join them together (the `i` and `c` are just shortcuts which make it easier to read the query).

You can also modify this with a `WHERE` after the `ON` row to narrow down your results, such as something like this (assuming you are looking for a specific invoice numbered 12345

```
SELECT * 
FROM invoices i
JOIN customer c
ON c.invoice = i.invoice
WHERE i.invoice = 12345
ORDER BY i.invoice
```

SQL is pretty powerful.  If you want to read up more, there are some great tutorials here on this site:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

If you want to call this in your query (using the first example) you can just do it the same way you were, like so:

```
 while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["invoice"];

}
```

**Edit:**
In the future it is better to declare your keys in the select.   Assuming that `customer_name` is in the customer table,  you would call it as `c.customer_name` in the select.  However, here's how it would work with the wildcard to get everything from both tables.  Change your query to this:

```
SELECT i.*, c.*
FROM invoices i
JOIN customer c
ON c.invoice = i.invoice
ORDER BY i.invoice
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 $query = "SELECT c.customer_name, i.* FROM invoices as i JOIN customers as c ON i.customer_id = c.id ORDER BY i.invoice ASC";
```

this will give you customer name as you require.

Refer to http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM Invoices I, Customers C 
          WHERE I.invoice = C.invoice
          ORDER BY C.invoice ASC";
```

If you would prefer a statement without joins..

Comment: Returning no results now also would i still output like this? $row["invoice"]

Comment: make sure the table and column names match yours exactly.. `$row["invoice"]` works as long as the row you are trying to retrieve is in your `SELECT` statement

Comment: All is showing apart from the customers_name - im using $query = "SELECT * 
          FROM invoices i, customers c 
          WHERE i.invoice = c.invoice
          ORDER BY c.invoice ASC";

Comment: did you try `$row["name"]`.. ?